# If $f(3)=5$ and $\frac{df}{dx}>-1$, what is the biggest value of $f(0)$ on $(-1,4)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inequality

> If $f(3)=5$ and $\dfrac{df}{dx}>-1$, what is the biggest value of $f(0)$ on $(-1,4)$?

As the title says, I don't really know how to start this, I've tried to some monotony or adding functions, but really can't figure it out, please help

Comment: You might try some straight lines with slopes that satisfy the constraint to get a feel

Comment: I don't understand, sorry

Comment: Your revision makes the "on $ (-1,4)$ not needed.  Let $f(x)=mx+b$.  You can find $b$ as a function of $m$ so $f(3)=5$  What is $\frac {df}{dx}?$.  Just pick some values for $m$ and see what $f(0)$ comes out to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overkill?

MVT:

$\dfrac{f(3)-f(0)}{3}=f'(s)$, $s \in (0,3)$;

$5-f(0)=3f'(s)>-3$;

$8>f(0)$, i.e. $8$ is an upper bound.

See Ross' comments.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Not important. Pleasure. Try to join (0,y) and (3,5) by a straight line as suggested by Ross. What happens for m=-1, m >-1? If you use a line : f'(s)=m. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(x_0)=g(x_0), f'(x)>g'(x)\implies f(x)\ge g(x)$$

Comment: Like, derivative of f is bigger than 0? Sorry, I don't know how to continue

Comment: Actually, the maximum of $f(0) $ happens only when the function is at the peak of its descending i.e. when $f'(x)=-1$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz:  but we are given $f'(x) \gt -1$, so it cannot equal $-1$.  The question has changed since your answer.